# How do I install Office 2010 on Windows 8 when the setup stops working?

Tags: microsoft-office-2010, windows-8-preview

I have installed Windows 8 developer preview.
Now i want install Microsoft Office 2010 on it but when i click on setup, it shows an error message

> Microsoft setup bootstrapper has stopped working.
>
> A problem caused the program the stop working correctly. Windows will
>   close the program and notify you if a solution is available.

Comment: for production machines don't use developer previews

Comment: My freind update windows 7 to 8 and working but i install from boot so not working. :(

Comment: Do not use developer preview productiv! Even the first startup of win8 says that!

Comment: @MichaelK: I'm using Windows 8 DP in a productive environment, there's not really an issue with that if you know the ropes. The above mentioned problem however is something that although isn't supported by Microsoft so I doubt if someone will come up with a fix. Haven't tried it myself yet, but it's most likely related to a missing component (C++ runtimes or .NET), DEP protection, UAC permissions or the necessity to run the installer in compatibility mode. I might try to install Office sooner or later to see whether it comes up for me too and if it's an easy fix...

Answer (score 2):

Fix: Uninstall Windows 8!

It's a 'Developer Preview' so not even close to being final - or even Beta for that matter!

Comment: Yet, I've been running Windows 8 Developer Preview as my main OS without any problems since it's start. Your suggestion is outside the boundaries specified by the question so it's not a fix...

Comment: You also mention above that you've not attempted to install Office 2010, nor is it listed anywhere on the Microsoft site as being supported. The clue is in it's name 'Developer Preview'.  Developers (such as yourself?) should be using it to preview their Applications (and in theory iron out any issues) before Alpha/Beta, not to be used in any kind of 'standard' workstation/production enviroment. :)

Comment: Please note that both me and Farshad are developers, so uninstalling the Windows 8 Developer preview is not a fix. Who knows we are trying to develop a Metro application that needs Microsoft Office 2010 components to function, like showing information that is stored within Outlook 2010 in a Metro application (like tasks/calender/contacts/...). That makes this a compeletly valid question, he doesn't necessarily need to specify his intentions with installing Office 2010 on a Developer Preview....

Comment: Note accepted, as a side note - i would expect much more information in Farshad's initial post considering that (in theory) he is technical enough to be a developer... A vague initial post with no specifications of his useage really does hint at a non-technical user 'reaching out' for assistance and clarification of just exactly what Windows 8 'Developer Preview' is intended for as an OS.

Comment: Agreed, it runs out in a few months anyway. I'm running mine of a VHD together with some Junction Points so that switching back to Windows 7 is just a matter of a reboot and everything would be very similar. But I don't think others will want to spent time on something that is not guaranteed to work just to reinstall it again in a few months. I don't see any problem with running it as a main OS though, but anyone's mileage may vary. Lost data? Broken hardware? Security leaks? It's bleeding edge, as they call it...

Comment: "Bleeding Edge" has certainly summed up some of Microsoft's implementations and 'features' in bygone Windows versions... Can't expect them to change their ways now... ;)

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded the Windows 8 Developer Preview to Consumer Preview.  MS Office 2007 installed without problem.  I assume I could have used Office 2010 just as easily.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running Windows8 pro build 9200. It is not any kind of consumer or developer preview, but still having the same problem when trying to install Microsoft office, the 2013 version in particular. All the other installs I have done so far though, including office 2010 worked fine.

Comment: I have installed 2013. No pains here. Windows 8 Pro Build 9200